# When is the radius of convergence of the product of two complex power series twice the radius of convergence of the product of the radii

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

Proving that the product has a larger radius then the product isn't too bad using the nth root test, but another practice question I have asks for examples of power series $\sum a_kz^k$ with radius of convergence $R_a$ and $\sum b_kz^k$ with radius of convergence $R_b$ such that $\sum a_k b_kz^k$ has twice the radius of the products, i.e. $R_{ab}=2R_aR_b$.

I'm not interested in the answer so much as how you approach these problems. I tend to be bad at thinking up examples, especially since I haven't computed many radii of convergence. Would the ratio test be useful to think about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To approach this problem, you need to know how exact the radius of convergence is related to the terms of the Taylor series. The result you need is the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem.

**Edit:** Using the theorem, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{R_a} &= \lim \sup \lvert a_n \rvert^{\frac{1}{n}} \\
\frac{1}{R_b} &= \lim \sup \lvert b_n \rvert^{\frac{1}{n}} \\
\frac{1}{R_{ab}} &= \lim \sup \lvert a_n b_n \rvert^{\frac{1}{n}}
\end{align*}

so can you think of a two sequences such that the lim sup of the product is half the product of the lim sup? Perhaps you can use the standard trick of staggering terms of the sequence, e.g.
$$ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots $$